# How to detect keyboard language in textview?

Tags: android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FnGoZ.jpg)

```
binding.etShortText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus) {
                String language = getKeyboardLanguage();
                Log.d("language is", language);
                binding.txtDetectLang.setText(language);
            }
        }
    });
}

private String getKeyboardLanguage() {
    InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    InputMethodSubtype inputMethodSubtype = inputMethodManager.getCurrentInputMethodSubtype();
    return inputMethodSubtype.getLocale();
}
```

Comment: it is not working

Comment: Please use code formatting to make it readable. Then ask a question, what is exactly your problem ?

Comment: what is getKeyboardLanguage() ?

Comment: when open keyboard in edittext than set language on textview simple...i have searched enough on net still i did not get correct answer

Comment: i have used inputMethodManager it is not working also

Comment: @RamMohandubey what is inside your `getKeyboardLanguauge` function ?

Comment: @RamMohandubey I don't think the keyboard has a specific language attribute set somewhere. I think the keyboard language is the language of the phone. You can obtain it using a [Locale](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html) object

Comment: private String getKeyboardLanguage() {
        InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        InputMethodSubtype inputMethodSubtype = inputMethodManager.getCurrentInputMethodSubtype();
        return inputMethodSubtype.getLocale();
    }

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

InputMethodSubtype ims = imm.getCurrentInputMethodSubtype();

String locale = ims.getLocale();

//get Locale object first 
Locale locale = new Locale(localeString);
//then get the display language from locale object.
String currentLanguage = locale.getDisplayLanguage();
//Also note that this method is deprecated in API 24. For API 24 or further use getLanguageTag() method.
```

You can try this code to get Current Keyboard Language regional code.

Comment: i have tried this also without any error but by default it is showing only english us on change keyboard it is not working

Comment: only work for one language i have already done this same as you answer

Comment: You can get keyboard language by first detecting the locale of device keyboard and then getting the Locale object from it.

Comment: getLocale() method in InputMethodSubtype was deprecated in API 24 according to the documentation. Documentation suggests using getLanguageTag() instead. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodSubtype.html#getLocale()

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to get language of the software keyboard's language. You can use [InputMethodManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodManager.htm) to get information about input types in Android.

```
private String getKeyboardLanguage(){
    String language = "";

    // This will give you to access input method manager
    InputMethodManager im = (InputMethodManager)Context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

    // Input methods has several subtypes, this will return the active one
    InputMethodSubtype subtype = im.getCurrentInputMethodSubtype();

    if(subtype != null){ // subtype can be null
        // Returns BCP-47 Language Tag or returns empty string if not specified
        language = getLanguageTag();
    }
    return language;
}
```

Comment: Error in getCurrentMethodSubtype and getCurrentMethodSubtype

Comment: "Error" is not a descriptive comment, can you provide detailed error message or code? If you're debugging, you should found message in red color in "Debug" panel on Android Studio. @RamMohandubey

Comment: I wrote method name wrongly, it should've been "getCurrentInputMethodSubtype()"

Comment: I am not getting error anything only by default on language "en" only